# Find records from table A that have certain JOINS into table C on the other side of pivot B, but not others

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables `products`, `product_stores` and `stores`. There's only a few entries in the `stores` table, and `product_stores` records basically means we know a certain products are carried at certain stores.

What we want to find is a set of products that are carried in stores 2, 3, 4, 5, but NOT in store 9.

Here's what I've got so far, unsure I'm on the right track, but it looks kind of close. I've got all the records where we know a product exists, but can't get the stores where the product isn't carried JOIN(ed) in...

```
SELECT s.id AS store_id, ps.id AS product_store_id, p.id AS product_id
FROM stores s
LEFT JOIN product_stores ps ON ps.store_id = s.id
RIGHT JOIN products p ON p.id = ps.product_id AND p.id = 8
HAVING store_id IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 9)
```

This produces

```
+----------+------------------+------------+
| store_id | product_store_id | product_id |
+----------+------------------+------------+
|        2 |           178455 |          8 |
|        3 |                8 |          8 |
|        4 |           178454 |          8 |
|        5 |           178453 |          8 |
+----------+------------------+------------+
```

What I want to see instead is this

```
+----------+------------------+------------+
| store_id | product_store_id | product_id |
+----------+------------------+------------+
|        2 |           178455 |          8 |
|        3 |                8 |          8 |
|        4 |           178454 |          8 |
|        5 |           178453 |          8 |
|        9 |             NULL |          8 |
+----------+------------------+------------+
```

Or since I really just want a unique list of product_id(s), something that flattens it out into a result set with unique product_id(s).

We're using MySQL. You should be able to see the relationships between the tables from my current query, but LMK if you need additional info. The `AND p.id = 8` is only there to limit the result set for testing purposes.

Comment: have you a fiddle example ? you have 5k and you didnt give fiddle ?

Comment: A fiddle? I've never used fiddle before...

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner joins should be fine for this:

```
SELECT ps.product_id
FROM stores s INNER JOIN
     product_stores ps
     ON ps.store_id = s.id 
GROUP BY ps.product_id
HAVING SUM(store_id = 2) > 0 and
       SUM(stored_id = 3) > 0 and
       SUM(stored_id = 4) > 0 and
       SUM(stored_id = 5) > 0 and
       SUM(stored_id = 9) = 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause tests that the product is in one of the stores.  The `sum()` calculates the number of rows in the store and the `> 0` says there is at least one for stores 2-5.  The `= 0` means that the product is not in store 9.